# If $ \int^{\pi}_0 (f(x)+f''(x))\sin(x)dx=2$ then find $f(0)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ be a function such that $f$ and $f''$ are continuous on $[0 , \pi]$, $f(\pi)=1$ and $$ \int^{\pi}_0 (f(x)+f''(x))\sin(x)dx=2.$$
>   Find $f(0)$.

My work. The only progress I have got is to split the integral as such 
$f(\pi)=1$ and $$ \int^{\pi}_0 (f(x)+f''(x))\sin(x)dx=2\Leftrightarrow \int^{\pi}_0 f(x)\sin(x)+\int^{\pi}_0 f''(x)\sin(x)dx=2.$$
Then I have trouble on how to continue..

Comment: Note that $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x \;dx=-\cos x\big\vert_{0}^{\pi}=2$ already; so $f(x)=1$ satisfies the conditions of the problem (and $f(0)=1$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By integration by parts,
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}f''(x)\sin(x)\,dx = \left. f'(x)\sin(x)\right|_{0}^{\pi}-\int_{0}^{\pi}f'(x)\cos(x)\,dx $$
and:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}f'(x)\cos(x)\,dx = \left.f(x)\cos(x)\right|_{0}^{\pi}+\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(x)\,dx $$
so the initial constraint can be simply re-written as
$$ f(\pi)+f(0) = 2. $$

---

An alternative approach. Assuming that 
$$ f(x)=C+\sum_{n\geq 1}s_n \sin(nx)+\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n \cos(nx) $$
the constraint $f\in C^2$ ensures that $\{s_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ and $\{c_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ are summable and the Fourier series is pointwise convergent. The constraint $f(\pi)=1$ translates into
$$ C + \sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n c_n = 1 $$
and the integral constraint translates into:
$$ C + \sum_{n\geq 1}c_{2n} = 1,$$
so:
$$ f(0)-f(\pi)=2\sum_{n\geq 1}c_{2n-1} = 0.$$